# как сделать ограничение области нажатия экрана?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Попробовал создать изображение, сделал его прозрачным и растянул в местах где хочу чтобы искались тачи игрока и накинул на него скрипт. Но мой скрипт ищет тачи по всему экрану. Как ограничить скрипт в пределах объекта или сделать так чтобы он не взаимодействовал например со слоем UI? Заранее спасибо!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class ScreenD : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject gm;
    private Attack1 at1;
    private int dir = 0; //if -1=left,0=stay,1=right

    public int Dir
    {
        get { return dir; }
        set { dir = value; }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        at1 = GameObject.Find("Ronin").GetComponent<Attack1>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && at1.Pressed == true) // поиск тачей, at1 это кнопка из другого скрипта нужная для того чтобы поиск тачей активировался только когда она нажата
        {
            var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2)
            {
                dir = -1;
            }
            else if (touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2)
            {
                dir = 1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `OnMouseDown()` для вашего изображения

Comment: не подходит. если использовать этот метод то внутри него не будут отслеживаться тачи

Comment: вы точно все делаете правильно? [Документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)